Reassign tasks on Team Planner view without changing the time
I have a project with roughly 500 tasks, and have now leveled it to fit within the resources I have given it.  One of my resources is called "Logistics Team", and I have played with max units of this in order to balance between the duration and the costs of hiring extra teams.  I arrived at a value of five as being optimal.
Now I would like to plan the work of each of the individual five teams, and so have created five new resources -- Logistics Team A, Logistics Team B, etc.
My intention was to take the nicely leveled plan from the Team Planner and reassign tasks from the "Logistics Team" resource to each of the individual teams, but when doing this my tasks start times are changed in such a way that I have lots of over-allocations.
Is there a way to reassign tasks such that nothing else about the task changes?

smolloy, After giving an answer I begin thinking, you leveled the plan because you had just one team resource "Logistics Team" which apparently was overallocated. But now you plan to use 5 separate teams which will likely eliminate overallocation and hence the need for leveling. So, what am I missing?

Not quite.  I needed to find a balance between the cost of hiring those extra teams and the duration of the project.  I could hire more teams so as to completely remove the overallocation, but it would require the hiring of a very costly number of teams.  So I settled on an intermediate number based on the requirements for the duration of the project and the likely budget for hiring temporary staff.
So the overallocation is reduced, but still very high.  Which is why I needed to level.

Okay, but by using 5 teams instead of one, the original level plan is no longer valid. What you need to do is to assign the new teams, see how that plays out and then re-level as necessary.

Not quite.  I don't think I am explaining myself properly.
I have leveled with the equivalent of five teams.  I.e., the "Logistics Team" has 500% resource.  Now I want to figure out how each team will be working, and so I need to give them a label -- Team A, Team B, etc.
So, MS Project has given me a plan that includes five teams.  Now I want to get a list of what each of those five teams will be doing on any particular day.

smolloy, A single resource with 500% max units is NOT equivalent to five teams with 100% max units. The leveling you obtained with the single team will not translate for five separate teams, it's like comparing apples and oranges. I suggest you either try the method I offered in my original answer, or start over with five separate teams and then level.

Thanks.  I admit my understanding of MS Project is very lacking.
When I levelled the 500% team, I got five nice rows of different jobs being done in the timeline view.  All I wanted to do was to take these five rows, and assign each one to a separate team so I could then start planning the work with the people in question.
But as you have already guessed, most of this comes from my inexperience with MSProject.  I am sure I am barking up the wrong tree.

smolloy, There is a lot of misunderstanding of what Project's leveling algorithm is designed to do and also what it is not designed to do. For example, some users assume it will help optimize resource usage and it definitely does not do that. It may help alleviate overallocation of resources but the result of its shifting assignments to alleviate the overallocation must be carefully reviewed to insure the result is workable in the real world.

Here's an idea that worked for me.

Select the Gantt Chart or Task Usage view.
Add the Leveling Delay field as a column in the view.
From the Gantt Chart view or Task Usage view display the Resource Assignment window.
Make a note of the value in the Leveling Delay field. It will be something like xedays. You might want to write it down as you will need that value later.
For each task, select the "Logistics Team" resource in the Resource Assignment window.
Hit the "Replace" button. A small Replace Resource window will pop up.
Select the replacement resource (e.g. "Logistics Team A") and hit "OK".
The new team resource will be assigned
Enter the value you saved in step 4 into the Leveling Delay field. That should re-establish the aforementioned leveling delay and the desired leveled dates.

A bit tedious but it might be the only viable solution unless someone else has a better approach.
